# html select options ordered by value in ie

Tags: html, sorting, internet-explorer, html-select

I have a following problem: my dropdown menu should be alphabeticaly ordered and it works in firefox but internet explorer seems to order items by value and not given order - how can I change this? (I can't change values as they are IDs)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something in my understanding of them, browsers will only show dropdown values (options) in the order that the values are provided in the HTML. So there must be something else at play here (**EDIT**, obviously client-side script can also effect the values, I'm talking direct HTML)

Comment: ok, it seems to be a jquery's fault when generating options in id order

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed the same behavior. Safari and Firefox keep the list elements ordered as provided in the HTML code, while Internet Explorer does sort them by value - which i'd consider a bug.

This happens with the latest versions of these browsers as of september 2012.

There seem to be no information regarding this issue... like everyone is using sequential values for their combos and lists.

Comment: I figured out it was jQuery bug in IE. If I use standard JS functions to create an options list everything works fine